# Why is ethanol used in catalytic reduction of nitro group to an amine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, nitro-compounds

$$\ce{R-NO2 +C2H5OH + H2 (g)->[Pt/Pd/Ni] R-NH_2}$$

The above equation represents catalytic reduction of nitro group to amine. What is the role of ethanol in it?

I understand that $\ce{Pt/Pd/Ni}$ plays an important role as reducing agent and hydrogen gas replaces oxygen atoms. But, I'm not able to understand the role of ethanol. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Solvent? You're missing the actual reductant, which is presumably hydrogen gas.

Comment: Provide conditions. Ethanol may be the reductant.

Comment: The above equation does **not** represent the catalytic reduction of a nitro compound to an amine! As mentioned by @orthocresol, you're missing the hydrogen gas! I've done the reaction very often with nitro arenes. Ethanol as a solvent is great because it dissolves both starting materials and products (only the catalyst, e.g. Pd/C is suspended and can be filtered off later). It is cheap, can be removed easily on a rotavap and, in contrast to methanol, isn't overly harmful.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for not mentioning Hydrogen. I did miss a really important reactant there. And thank you @Klaus-DieterWarzecha for making me understand the role of ethanol as a solvent.

Comment: Note that Pt/Pd/Ni is definitely a catalyst here and should be denoted differently (not as reactant). I suppose the same goes for the ethanol (solvent), but since it's a part of a question, I left it as it is, but still the reaction is incomplete. Is there water among the products?